# Reducer returns object instead of array

Tags: javascript, redux

I have an odd problem with my reducer. It returns an object instead of array. How can I fix this?

```
export function reducer(state = {cart: []}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART": {
      let oldState = [...state.cart]


      let index = oldState.findIndex(x => x.name === action.payload.name)


      return index > -1 ? {...state, cart: oldState} : {...state, cart: Object.assign({}, action.payload, {quantity: action.payload + 1 })} 


    }
    default: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: For clarification I'm trying to add the action payload to the cart array if it doesn't exist and increment quantity and then just increment quantity if it does already exits in the cart array. State is supposed to be an object and cart is supposed to be an array. Cart seems to return an object when I expect an array.

P.S. I'm dangerous with ES6...

Comment: It's supposed to return an object. Plus, your action never does anything. You never put anything into the actual array.

Comment: I updated the code. I still don't get the desired result.

Comment: `return { ...something }` will obviously return an object, and is also redundant. Is equivalent to `return something`. I think you don't understand what the [spread operator  (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) does.  Why do you expect this function to return an array?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the spread operator...

Comment: Your initialized your state as an object. Doing state = [] in your reducer argument would make it an array.

Comment: I apologize.. let me clarify, cart should be an array state should be an object

Comment: Have you tried console logging index before you hit the return statement? Clearly your hitting the false portion of your ternary statement, resulting in your code turning cart into an object.

Comment: Interestingly enough console.log doesn't work in my reducer. It doesn't even fire. I wonder if it's a create react app thing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a problem here:

```
cart: Object.assign({}, action.payload, {quantity: action.payload + 1 })}
```

I suggest that it should be like this:

```
cart: [...oldState, Object.assign({}, action.payload, {quantity: action.payload + 1 })]
```

but this part `Object.assign({}, action.payload, {quantity: action.payload + 1 }` is really disturbing. You are using `action.payload` as an object and right after it - `action.payload + 1` as a number.

and if you want to increase the `quantity` - then

```
if (index > -1) {
  oldState[index] = {...oldState[index], quantity: oldState[index].quantity + 1};
  return {...state, cart: oldState};
} else {
  oldState.push({...action.payload, quantity: 0});
  return {...state, cart: oldState};
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to add the action payload to the cart array if it doesn't exist and increment quantity and then just increment quantity if it does already exits in the cart array

Comment: Was it in the original question? Please update the question then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
{...state, cart: Object.assign({}, action.payload, {quantity: action.payload + 1 })}
```

This is equivalent to this piece of procedural code:

```
const newCart =
  Object.assign({}, action.payload, {quantity: action.payload + 1 }

Object.assign({}, state, { cart: newCart });
```

`Object.assign` accepts any number of arguments as long as they all are all objects, then merges the properties of them, from right to left.

You expect the property `cart` in the returned object to be an array, while you are clearing assigning an object to it.